# Is it possible to step through native code in the Edge (or any browser's) debugger?

Tags: javascript, svg, microsoft-edge, data-uri

Straightforward question. I am currently debugging an issue where this doesn't render properly on Edge despite being able to render on pretty much any other browser:

```js
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  console.log("succ");
}
img.onerror = function(error) {
  console.log(error);
}
img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><style>polygon { fill: black } div {color: white;font:18px serif;height: 100%;overflow: auto;}</style><polygon points="5,5 195,10 185,185 10,195" /><!-- Common use case: embed HTML text into SVG --><foreignObject x="20" y="20" width="160" height="160"><!--In the context of SVG embeded into HTML, the XHTML namespace couldbe avoided, but it is mandatory in the context of an SVG document--><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Sed mollis mollis mi ut ultricies. Nullam magna ipsum,porta vel dui convallis, rutrum imperdiet eros. Aliquamerat volutpat.</div></foreignObject></svg>'
document.getElementById("target").append(img);
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

When I step into the code, there is clearly an error with how `Image` is being instantiated with its `src` property. But I can't step into the browser code to see why it's not working. Is it possible to do this somehow?

Comment: Hi, please include the code from your CodePen here in the question itself rather than circumventing the rules in order to post such a link without any code in your question.

Comment: fixed, i used the built in codepen feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing your code on my side, it seems the issue is related to the height property in the style.

Try to remove the height property from this part of code

> div {color: white;font:18px serif; <s>height: 100%;</s>overflow:
>   auto;}

Then, the code as below:

```
<div id="target"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        console.log("succ");
    }
    img.onerror = function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><style>polygon { fill: black } div {color: white;font:18px serif;overflow: auto;}</style><polygon points="5,5 195,10 185,185 10,195" /><!-- Common use case: embed HTML text into SVG --><foreignObject x="20" y="20" width="160" height="160"><!--In the context of SVG embeded into HTML, the XHTML namespace couldbe avoided, but it is mandatory in the context of an SVG document--><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Sed mollis mollis mi ut ultricies. Nullam magna ipsum,porta vel dui convallis, rutrum imperdiet eros. Aliquamerat volutpat.</div></foreignObject></svg>'
    img.style = "height :100%";
    document.getElementById("target").append(img);
</script>
```

The result [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFvEC.png).

Comment: Yeah I stepped through. It turns out edge doesn't like the percent sign, it thinks it's not properly escaped. Running the URL through an encoding function solved my problem.